# reading and xml response with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml

I am trying to return information from an API (BBB actually) which response does look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<response>
    <returncode>SUCCESS</returncode>
    <meetingID>ldapreader</meetingID>
    <attendeePW>accounts123</attendeePW>
    <moderatorPW>accounts456</moderatorPW>
    <createTime>1485524358342</createTime>
    <voiceBridge>24686</voiceBridge>
    <dialNumber>613-555-1234</dialNumber>
    <createDate>Fri Jan 27 14:39:18 CET 2017</createDate>
    <hasUserJoined>false</hasUserJoined>
    <duration>0</duration>
    <hasBeenForciblyEnded>false</hasBeenForciblyEnded>
    <messageKey>duplicateWarning</messageKey>
    <message>
        This conference was already in existence and may currently be in progress.
    </message>
</response>
```

as Chrome says, This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it...

I have written this as a script base on some post I found on this site, but I am stuck...

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

    function myCall() {
        var request = $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo $fulllink; ?>",
            type: "GET",            
            dataType: "xml"
        });

        request.done(function(xml) {
                  // Parse the xml file and get data
        var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml),
            $xml = $(xmlDoc);
        $xml.find('response').each(function () {
            $("#mybox").append($(this).text() + "<br />");
        });
          //  $("#mybox").html(xml);          
        });

        request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
            alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
        });
    }
</script>
      <style type="text/css">
            #mybox {
                width: 300px;
                height: 250px;
                border: 1px solid #999;
            }
        </style>
 <input type="button" value="Update" onclick="myCall()" /> 
     <div id="mybox">  </div>
```

No matter what I try to find (response or returncode , message...) my div remain empty and I don't see any error in the debug Tools of Chrome. I can see the XHR request fine...

Maybe someone with deeper knowledgde can help me?
Thanks for your lights!
Cedric

Comment: Your title mentions PHP, but there is no PHP code here, only JavaScript.

Comment: debug around within your done callback. One of your jquery filtering/selecting methods aren't finding anything. Which one is it? It's certainly possible that .find isn't finding `response` due to `response` being the root. Additionally, `response` node doesn't contain text... so... clearly that wouldn't return anything?

Comment: @KevinB You're right but I tried with message or meetingID or any other  but it still does not read anything from the xml...  I tried to add the xml header as suggested below liek this:
  var $xml1= $(xml);
  var xml2='<?xml version="1.0"?>'+$xml1;
        var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml2);
but it still does not work....

Comment: you shouldn't need to use $.parseXML, jquery does that for you since you used dataType:xml.

Comment: `$( xml ).find( "meetingID" ).text()` should be more than enough to get the meetingID text.. Log that value

Comment: How do I log that?

Comment: @KevinB thanks a lot, I think I got it working. with this
  var $xml1= $(xml);
  var xml2='<?xml version="1.0"?>'+$xml1;
        //var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml2);
        $xml = $(xml2);
  var returncode= $( xml ).find( "returncode" ).text();
  var meetingID= $( xml ).find( "meetingID" ).text();
   $("#mybox").append($(this).text() +returncode+ "<br />");  
   $("#mybox").append($(this).text() +meetingID+ "<br />");
Thanks all!:

Answer (score 1):

You can done this by using [`jQuery.parseXML()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/), which

> ... uses the native parsing function of the browser to create a valid XML Document. This document can then be passed to jQuery to create a typical jQuery object that can be traversed and manipulated.

```
var xml="<?xml version="1.0"?>
<response>
    <returncode>SUCCESS</returncode>
    <meetingID>ldapreader</meetingID>
    <attendeePW>accounts123</attendeePW>
    <moderatorPW>accounts456</moderatorPW>
    <createTime>1485524358342</createTime>
    <voiceBridge>24686</voiceBridge>
    <dialNumber>613-555-1234</dialNumber>
    <createDate>Fri Jan 27 14:39:18 CET 2017</createDate>
    <hasUserJoined>false</hasUserJoined>
    <duration>0</duration>
    <hasBeenForciblyEnded>false</hasBeenForciblyEnded>
    <messageKey>duplicateWarning</messageKey>
    <message>
        This conference was already in existence and may currently be in progress.
    </message>
</response>";  
  xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),
      $xml = $( xmlDoc ),
      $meetingID = $xml.find( "meetingID" );


$( "#anotherElement" ).append( $meetingID.text() );
```

Comment: Hi Hassan, Thanks for you answer.
I have changed my code to this,
        var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml);
        $xml = $(xmlDoc);
 $meetingID = $xml.find( "meetingID" );
        $( "#mybox" ).append( $meetingID.text() );
  });

but it still does not work.. any ideas?

Comment: @HassanALi jQuery automagically uses $.parseXML when using the "xml" dataType.

Answer (score -1):

With [**simpleXML**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php), it’s as easy as reading the XML and then accessing it’s contents through an easy to read object.

```
<?php

$xml="<?xml version='1.0'?>
<response>
   <returncode>SUCCESS</returncode>
   <meetingID>ldapreader</meetingID>
   <attendeePW>accounts123</attendeePW>
   <moderatorPW>accounts456</moderatorPW>
   <createTime>1485524358342</createTime>
   <voiceBridge>24686</voiceBridge>
   <dialNumber>613-555-1234</dialNumber>
   <createDate>Fri Jan 27 14:39:18 CET 2017</createDate>
   <hasUserJoined>false</hasUserJoined>
   <duration>0</duration>
   <hasBeenForciblyEnded>false</hasBeenForciblyEnded>
   <messageKey>duplicateWarning</messageKey>
   <message>
       This conference was already in existence and may currently be in progress.
   </message>
</response>";


$xmlString=simplexml_load_string($xml);
echo $xmlString->returncode[0];


?>
```

Comment: This is not a PHP question

Comment: So you should delete this answer

Comment: reading and xml response with php / ajax ---- thats his question so how i can consider its not a php question

Comment: @miken32  Addden has told him and Simple Php Method to Read Xml .So We  have to encourage him for answering.

Comment: Thanks you Adden, but I do not see how I can implement this with my button? I have no access to the API rendering the xml...